# How can I disable scientific notation in fwrite data.table in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to disable scientific notation when writing numbers to csv files in data.table. I can do that with `write.csv` using `options(scipen = 999)` but not with `fwrite`.
Example:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table("ID" = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), VALUE = c(0.0000001, 0.1234567, 1000000, 1234567))
options(scipen = 999)
write.csv(dt, row.names = FALSE)
# "ID","VALUE"
# "A",0.0000001
# "B",0.1234567
# "C",1000000
# "D",1234567
fwrite(dt, row.names = FALSE)
# ID,VALUE
# A,1e-07
# B,0.1234567
# C,1e+06
# D,1234567
```

I would like line A and C in fwrite to be written as in write.csv. I am using data.table version 1.10.0. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Try with `format` i.e. `dt <- dt[, lapply(.SD, format, scientific = FALSE)]`

Comment: Thanks @akrun, This works but is very slow (my DT has 300 milion rows...). I was looking for something more efficient.

Comment: This is an outstanding issue: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2020

Try giving a +1 over there and follow it for updates.

Comment: for integer values up to a certain size, using `bit64::as.integer64` was an acceptable workaround for my use case.  That won't help you with decimal places though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is now fixed in data.table v1.12.4. Function `fwrite` gains option `scipen`. Quote from data.table github site: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md

"*Gains scipen #2020, the number 1 most-requested feature #3189. The default is `getOption("scipen")` so that `fwrite` will now respect R's option in the same way as `base::write.csv` and `base::format`, as expected. The parameter and option name have been kept the same as base R's scipen for consistency and to aid online search. It stands for 'scientific penalty'; i.e., the number of characters to add to the width within which non-scientific number format is used if it will fit. A high penalty essentially turns off scientific format. We believe that common practice is to use a value of 999, however, if you do use 999, because your data might include very long numbers such as 10^300, fwrite needs to account for the worst case field width in its buffer allocation per thread. This may impact space or time. If you experience slowdowns or unacceptable memory usage, please pass verbose=TRUE to fwrite, inspect the output, and report the issue. A workaround, until we can determine the best strategy, may be to pass a smaller value to scipen, such as 50. We have observed that `fwrite(DT, scipen=50)` appears to write 10^50 accurately, unlike base R. However, this may be a happy accident and not apply generally. Further work may be needed in this area.*"

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
require(data.table)
#Sample data
dt <- data.table("ID" = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), VALUE = c(0.0000001, 0.1234567, 1000000, 1234567))
dt

   ID        VALUE
1:  A 1.000000e-07
2:  B 1.234567e-01
3:  C 1.000000e+06
4:  D 1.234567e+06
```

Idea for a solution:

```
dt$VALUE <- format(dt$VALUE, scientific = FALSE) 
fwrite(dt, row.names = FALSE)
```

Results

```
ID,VALUE
A,      0.0000001
B,      0.1234567
C,1000000.0000000
D,1234567.0000000
```

## Edit - remove the trailing zeros.

In addition, if you'd like to remove the trailing zeros you can add the argument `drop0trailing = TRUE` to `format`.

```
dt$VALUE <- format(dt$VALUE, drop0trailing = TRUE, scientific = FALSE) 
fwrite(dt, row.names = FALSE)

ID,VALUE
A,      0.0000001
B,      0.1234567
C,1000000
D,1234567
```

Comment: you are still ending up with trailing zeros, I think you need a character conversion.  try `dt$VALUE <- sapply(dt$VALUE, format, scientific=FALSE)`

Comment: dt$VALUE <- sapply(dt$VALUE, format, scientific=FALSE), gave me the similar results to format(dt$VALUE, scientific = FALSE). Please see my edit